# Adding Google App Engine Backend to my App

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I am trying to develop an app that saves and storage Email and Password from an User. I followed the Google Cloud Platform Tutorial, but I still can`t figure out a way to connect my app (made using Android Studio) to the Google App Engine tools

This is my LoginActivity java class

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Pair<Context, String>, Void, String>

{
    LoginApi loginApiService = null;
    private Context context;

    AutoCompleteTextView email = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_email);
    String email2 = email.getText().toString();
    TextView senha = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_password);
    String senha2 = senha.getText().toString();

    private String userdata;

    @SafeVarargs
    protected final String doInBackground(Pair<Context, String>... params) {
        if (loginApiService == null) {  // Only do this once
            LoginApi.Builder builder = new LoginApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                    new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
                    // options for running against local devappserver
                    // - 10.0.2.2 is localhost's IP address in Android emulator
                    // - turn off compression when running against local devappserver
                    .setRootUrl("http://104.154.208.108:8080/_ah/api/")
                    .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new GoogleClientRequestInitializer() {
                        @Override
                        public void initialize(AbstractGoogleClientRequest<?> abstractGoogleClientRequest) throws IOException {
                            abstractGoogleClientRequest.setDisableGZipContent(true);
                        }
                    });
            // end options for devappserver

            loginApiService = builder.build();
        }

        context = params[0].first;
        String name = params[0].second;

        try {
            return loginApiService.sayHi(email2.getEmail()).execute().getData();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I am not sure about the IP number and this line " loginApiService.sayHi(email2.getEmail()).execute().getData(); "

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to connect to the productive Server you do not have to set the root Url and you do not have to disable gzip. This options are needed for your locale development server

EDIT:

See my example Code:

```
 if(LOCAL_RUN) { // my local development Server
           return new MyApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                    new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
                    .setRootUrl("http://192.168.0.235:8080/_ah/api/") //depends how you have configured your local server
                    .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new GoogleClientRequestInitializer() {
                        @Override
                        public void initialize(AbstractGoogleClientRequest<?> abstractGoogleClientRequest) throws IOException {
                            abstractGoogleClientRequest.setDisableGZipContent(true);
                       }
                    });
        } else { // the real App Engine Server
            return new MyApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                    new AndroidJsonFactory(), null));
        }
```

Comment: Should I delete the setUrl? Some tutorials say to put my app adress (the one generate in GAE) and I didn't know about the disablegzip, thank you!

Comment: I added an example how I connect to the productive server and to the local development server. You may check the generated client libs. You will find in one of the classes the real URL of your App Engine Project so you do not have to set the URL

Comment: Thanks! So, the real URL for mine is "...appspot.com" ?
I am new with using GAE as a server and Android Studio, and the tutorials are for most part quite incomplete.